# Unable to import 'angulars/router' in plnkr

Tags: angular

Plnkr is failing when i attempt to import the router class in my project

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
```

The following error is thrown:

```
VM883 zone.js:101GET https://npmcdn.com/@angular/src/directives/router_link_active
```

Here's the plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9okaVfVSsRhPxexP9HNw?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your systemjs config the following:

```
'@angular/router': {
  main: 'index.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/REhnE02IQyGAWpmy5Yty?p=preview)**

If you want to use old version of router then:

```
'@angular/router-deprecated': {
   main: 'index.js',
   defaultExtension: 'js'
}

import { RouteConfig } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

**[Plunker router deprecated](http://plnkr.co/edit/aKSGwIu8k6H4EbEsy4yY?p=preview)**

Comment: any clue why i receive the error RouteConfig is not a function ?

Comment: Check this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html. `RouteConfig` is deprecated.